# Which country am I from?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, computer-puzzle

Which country am I from? You have all the information you need inside the following picture.

[image]

Hint:

> Unicode decode (via binary).

> You might need Google Translate for this.

Comment: It looks like you've posted several similar-looking puzzles in the span of the last hour or so. While there's generally nothing wrong with this, it might be better for you to spread them out a bit so people don't get tired of these sorts of puzzles. That's totally up to you, though.

Comment: Post 1 every 24 hours if I were you!

Comment: Or... since the other people didn't suggest this: post multiple puzzles of different types. That would allow people a break from these kinds but also allow you to post more.

Comment: I think my puzzles are more variable right now?

Comment: This question probably got downvoted because it is ultimately very simple, only really requiring looking up a key on the internet (and then translating the answer). It's not that much of a puzzle, more an exercise in using web tools. In the same way, a question that is just a string of Morse code or semaphore flags isn't really a great 'puzzle'. It could, however, form _part_ of a puzzle. Consider adding additional steps before you arrive at the deciphering step in the image above, e.g. a grid of letters with a rule that certain ones must be blanked out.

Comment: Also, could you use white backgrounds to your diagrams, please, rather than transparent ones? They don't show up in dark mode on browsers. Thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry; I didn't know there is a dark mode on PSE. I'll change it next time.

Comment: @SnySmartie It's not about PSE specifically. It's just that many users have dark mode switched on in the settings of their browser of choice - using white backgrounds avoids the need to flick between modes... Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are from

> **CHINA**

> The picture represent 5 lines of binary strings. Where reading from left to right the black blocks represent 1s and the empty tiles represent 0s.

> Feeding all this into a binary to text translator with Unicode encoding I got 5 Chinese characters:

> [image]

> Which I when translated to English says **I am Chinese**!

> [image]